# How to run a java program in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'd like to ask how can I run this simple Hello World program in IntelliJ? I click the ‘run’ and I get no default run configuration. What I should do?
[image]

Comment: Can you show the project structure? It looks like your source file is not in a folder which is marked as "Source folder" in IntelliJ. That means that IntelliJ doesn't recognize this file as Java source file and also doesn't compile it.

Comment: @dunni That's the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It's ok now.This is how I did:

1. In project structure->Moduels->Sources,click"mark as sources";
   [image]
2. Moduels->Denpendencies,set Project SDK;
   [image]
3. Projects->set Project compiler output path.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Context-click in your code editor.
2. Choose menu item for `Run 'your-main-method-here()'`.

[image: screenshot of context-menu with item Run]

Notice the `Debug` menu item as well, to run with the debugger engaged.

---

Eventually you will need to learn about creating a `Run/Debug Configuration` setting ([see manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/run-debug-configuration.html)). But for starting out, the context-menu `Run` will suffice.

Getting started with [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) is quite awkward because of speed bumps like this. But the effort is well worth it; IntelliJ is a superb [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) once you get the hang of it.

Comment: In this case however, it looks like the source file is not in a source folder in IntelliJ (the icon looks a bit strange to me), so the menu entry might not be available.

Comment: @dunni Odd icon indeed. I do not see that file icon listed in Preferences > Editor > File Types.

Comment: @BasilBourque: after all that, the op [deleted his question with your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67994908/). That was not a kind action on the part of the OP